# XSL Merge nodes of same types having same class

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm very new to XSL and I'm trying to clean some XML in order to merge redondant tags (example spans below).

```
<body><!-- userBodyTop goes here -->
  <div class="header" />
  <div class="document">
     <p class="text">...</p>
     <p class="Normal">
        <span class="USous-article">§ 1er </span>
        <span class="USous-article">–</span>
        <span class="USous-article"> </span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus condimentum tortor purus, ut vulputate nisl lobortis ut. Fusce luctus massa nisl, ac tincidunt eros sodales consectetur. Nulla venenatis purus non bibendum ullamcorper. In ac augue consectetur, varius massa et, interdum sem. Proin rutrum ornare ligula ac varius. Proin vitae scelerisque libero, sit amet egestas orci. Mauris pharetra consectetur efficitur. Ut commodo diam nisl, eget semper lectus commodo sed. Donec turpis diam, aliquet sed sem ac.</p>
     <p class="text>some more text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footnotes" />
  <!-- userBodyTail goes here -->
</body>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is merging the text content of the `span`s having class "USous-article" :

```
<body><!-- userBodyTop goes here -->
  <div class="header" />
  <div class="document">
     <p class="text">...</p>
     <p class="Normal">
        <span class="USous-article">§ 1er – </span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus condimentum tortor purus, ut vulputate nisl lobortis ut. Fusce luctus massa nisl, ac tincidunt eros sodales consectetur. Nulla venenatis purus non bibendum ullamcorper. In ac augue consectetur, varius massa et, interdum sem. Proin rutrum ornare ligula ac varius. Proin vitae scelerisque libero, sit amet egestas orci. Mauris pharetra consectetur efficitur. Ut commodo diam nisl, eget semper lectus commodo sed. Donec turpis diam, aliquet sed sem ac.</p>
     <p class="text>some more text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footnotes" />
  <!-- userBodyTail goes here -->
</body>
```

I've tried multiple solutions (with preceding-sibling/following sibling) and this XSL 2.0 solution below that I didn't manage to make it work....

```
<xsl:template match="p[@class='Normal'][count(./span[@class='USous-article'])>0]">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="node() except text()[not(normalize-space())]" group-adjacent="boolean(self::*)">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="concat(node-name(.), '|', @class)">
          <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@class" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/node()" />
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Any idea ? I have no clues...

Comment: When I try your posted template in a minimal example at  http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kD it seems to merge the `span`s

Comment: hmm that's strange, so my problem is not really XSL. Another question : do you have an idea why the template is not applied to the nested `a` here ? Here is the link http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kD/3

Comment: You don't `apply-templates` to the nested `a` element as your code matches the `p` parent and then your grouping creates a new `a` element and simply `apply-templates` to its child nodes. I think that problem is more difficult and requires a new, separate question if you can't debug and solve it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:preserve-space elements="span"/>

  <xsl:template match="p[@class='Normal']">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="concat(name(), '/',  @class)">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
          <xsl:attribute name="class" select="@class"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the order of operations in template matching `p`:

- Replicate `p` element.
- Apply templates to attributes.
- For each group of adjacent nodes with the same name and class:

  - Replicate the element.
  - Replicate class attribute.
- Replicate the text of the current element.

Another important point to note is the usage of `strip-space` and `preserve-space`
commands:

- Strip space from all tags.
- Except of `span` tags, for which spaces are to be preserved.

Otherwise the space - content of the last `span` element would have been lost.

Comment: Won't this move any text before the spans to the end of the `p` (after the merged span)?

Comment: Yes, but the source example indicates that *span* tags are at the beginning and only after them occurs any "normal" text.